# How can i compare strings of two files in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, grep, cut

The first field is the username, the second is the password, and the last indicates the action (login/register)

File 1: User input

```
hello,world,register
```

File 2: Plain text database

```
admin,123
user,321
foo,bar
```

How can i compare the user input with the database to check if the username already exists?

I´ve tried the following code, but it´s not working:

```
if cut -d "," -f1 user_input | grep -wf user_input database; then
    echo "This username is already in use, try again!"
else
    echo "Successfully registered!"
fi
```

> **PS: i need a solution without awk,sed or find, just grep and cut**

Comment: Is `user_input` a file, or is it supposed to be an environment variable, or is the input string being piped to the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` + `cut` approach:

```
if grep -qwf <(cut -d, -f1 user_input) database; then 
    echo "This username is already in use, try again!"
else
    echo "Successfully registered!"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the `-f`

Comment: @user1404316, read documentation about `-f` option and read the 1st comment https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421837/how-can-i-compare-strings-of-two-files-in-shell-script/421841?noredirect=1#comment758925_421841

Comment: It worked! thank you a lot @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @HenriqueHBR, you're welcome

Comment: But why use the `-f` option at all?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that only uses `bash` built-in and `grep`.

```
while IFS=',' read -r username
do
    if grep -wq $username database
    then
        echo "This username is already in use, try again!"
    else
        echo "Successfully registered!"
    fi
done < user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

I done by using cut command,for loop and if condition

```
#!/bin/bash
 i=`cut -d "," -f1 user_input.txt`

#echo $i
for j in `cut -d "," -f1 database.txt`
do
if [[ $i == $j ]]
then
echo $j "already exsists"
else
echo $j "doesn't exsists"
fi
done
```